# Get an email on inbound message with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am currently using a Twilio phone number with ShortySMS for some SMS marketing. When a customer responds (sends me an inbound message), I want to get an email. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In twillio you set webhook that can push the data to web route. In that route you can send yourself the email with the content

Answer (score 1):

Twilios [Code Exchange](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange) has a [Quick Deploy](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/forward-sms-email) option for this scenario.  The Quick Deploy uses SendGrid as the mail sender so you'll need to have a SendGrid account in addition to your Twilio account.

The Quick Deploy utilizes a Twilio Function to run the code needed to take the incoming SMS message from Twilio, craft an email message and send it using the SendGrid API.  The code for that function is located in a [public Github repository](https://github.com/twilio-labs/function-templates/tree/main/forward-message-sendgrid) if you want to take a look at what its doing.

If you use the Quick Deploy, once the function is created you can then customize its code if you want to change the default templates behavior.

Hope that helps.